# Loop Using Large Number Not Working

Tags: javascript

This loop works:

```
var time;
for (time = 0; time < 5; time++) {
  // Runs 5 times
  console.log('Log');
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
var time;
for (time = 1490543999999999; time <= time - (518400000000 * 10) ; time = time - 518400000000) {
          console.log('Log');
      }
```

How come? Is it because the numbers are too large? How to solve this problem then?

Comment: The condition `time <= time - (518400000000 * 10)` is never true.

Comment: @trincot How is this supposed to run forever? `1490543999999999` is greater than `time - (518400000000 * 10)`

Comment: You're right, it doesn't enter at all.

Comment: http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

Comment: @amudhan3093 The numbers are all smaller than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: You can just have a normal loop and determine the time using a calculation like `var time = 1490543999999999 - (i * 518400000000)`. Eg: `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){var time = 1490543999999999 - (i * 518400000000)}`

Answer (score 0):

Two differences with the first loop:

- Since you are traversing in the opposite direction, you need the opposite comparison for the loop condition: `>` instead of `<=`.
- As you change the *time* variable, you cannot use it as boundary value. Use a different variable for that -- one that does not change from the initial value

```js
var time, initTime;
for (initTime = time = 1490543999999999; time > initTime - (518400000000 * 10) ; time = time - 518400000000) {
    console.log('Log');
}
```

Or better (to avoid recalculation of the limit):

```js
var time, endTime;
for (time = 1490543999999999, endTime = time - 518400000000 * 10; time > endTime; time -= 518400000000) {
    console.log('Log');
}
```